# Change color in part of my message

Tags: c#

I need to change my text color for specific word in my text. I have used to generate my text as below.

```
String message=string.empty; 
String message1=”something”;
String message2=”something”;
message += “My Message is”+ message1+ “and” + message2;
```

and I send this message as a email body. So I need to change text color only part of this message. Lets say I want to message2 as red color. How can I do this?
Thanx.

Comment: Where do you want the output of the message to be? In a window, a control or console? The color is not property of the string itself so you can't make a standard text with colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do this if you send the message as HTML. And then the code would be

```
string message1 = "something";
string message2 = "<font color='red'>something</font>";
message += "My message is " + message1 + " and " + message2;
```

Using HTML in email is different than using HTML to build web-pages.. A lot of "no-no"'s in webpages are a necessity in mail :|

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the e-mail as HTML format, you should be able to use normal HTML tags to achieve your goal (in the actual text of the message).  So you might write:

```
...+= "My Message is” + message1 + “and <font color=red>” + message2 + "</font>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the email supports an html body, you can try wrapping the part of the message you want colored in html `<font color="red"></font>` tags and then check if the resulting output functions as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If your sending a HTML email, you can use standard HTML tags like the [font](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp) tag:

```
<font color="red">Some text!</font>
```

Or you could use CSS:

```
<h3 style="color: #FF0000;">Some text!</h3>
```

If you are sending plain text email, there's no way to format your body.

Comment: Ahh. Is that soo. :( :( any way thanx for replies. And Stack overflow is very helpful one. thanx stack overflow team as well